# Spring Boot OAS3 API returns EPOCH not DateTime format

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I unable to get Date-Time format in my Spring Boot 3 API (OAS3) response.

I want to have Time Stamp Format but it returns an EPOCH time.
API was generated by openapi-generator-maven-plugin.

Some custom Jackson date mappers works but default serialization for object in controller not !

I try to

- set preferences in application.yaml
- set custom @Bean in SpringBootApplication to override mappings
- set custom formating on mapped object

but all without success.

Defined schema field in `api.yaml` contract

```
        sentDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
```

Generated java

```
@JsonProperty("sentDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(
        iso = ISO.DATE_TIME
    )
    private OffsetDateTime sentDate;
```

and response in EPOCH

```
        "sentDate": 1675435210.336232,
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a @EnableWebMvc adnotation im my WebMvcConfig class.
After removing it API returns Date in proper DateTime format !

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc <--- 
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {        
     registry.addMapping("/**");    }
}
```